# Magento 2 admin end drop down dependencies?

Tags: magento2, custom, dependency, fieldsets

In **Magento 2** at admin end from my custom module I have  two options 1) Level and 2) Segment in the drop down.

As well I have another multiselect dropdowns like Levels and segments

Now if i choose level i need to display levels multiselect dropdown
As well if i choose segment i need to display segments multiselect dropdown.

Please find the screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

I have referred one concept i.e field dependency at admin end for dropdown options how can we do this concept here.

Please check the below code

```
<?php

 
namespace Stackexchange\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Earningpointrule\Edit\Tab;

class Target extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
    /**
     * Wysiwyg config
     * 
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config
     */
    protected $_wysiwygConfig;

    /**
     * Country options
     * 
     * @var \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Locale\Country
     */
    protected $_countryOptions;

    /**
     * Country options
     * 
     * @var \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno
     */
    protected $_booleanOptions;

    /**
     * constructor
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig
     * @param \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Locale\Country $countryOptions
     * @param \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno $booleanOptions
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
        \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Locale\Country $countryOptions,
        \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno $booleanOptions,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_wysiwygConfig            = $wysiwygConfig;
        $this->_countryOptions           = $countryOptions;
        $this->_booleanOptions           = $booleanOptions;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        
        $post = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('stackexchange_custom_earningpointrule');
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('earningpointrule_');
        $form->setFieldNameSuffix('earningpointrule');
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            [
                'legend' => __('Target'),
                'class'  => 'fieldset-wide'
            ]
        );

            
       $parentField = $fieldset->addField('target_type', 
        'select', [
             'name' => 'target_type',
            'label' => __('Target Type'),
            'values' => $this->getTargetTypeOptions(),
            
        ]);         
        

        
        $childFieldOne= $fieldset->addField(
            'target_multiselect_levels',
            'multiselect',
            [
                'name'     => 'target_multiselect_levels',                
                'title' => __('Target Multiselect Levels'),
                'label' => __('Levels'),
                'required'=>true,               
                'values' => $this->getTagetTypeMultiselectLevels(),
                
            ]
        );
        
        $childFieldTwo=$fieldset->addField(
            'target_multiselect_segments',
            'multiselect',
            [
                'name'     => 'target_multiselect_segments',                
                'title' => __('Target Multiselect Segments'),
                'label' => __('Segments'),
                'required'=>true,
                'values' => $this->getTagetTypeMultiselectSegments(),
                
            ]
        );
        
        $dependence1 = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Element\Dependence')
        ->addFieldMap($parentField->getHtmlId(), $parentField->getName())
        ->addFieldMap($childFieldOne->getHtmlId(), $childFieldOne->getName())
        ->addFieldDependence(
            $childFieldOne->getName(),
            $parentField->getName(),
            '1'
            );
            
            $dependence2 = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Element\Dependence')
        ->addFieldMap($parentField->getHtmlId(), $parentField->getName())
        ->addFieldMap($childFieldTwo->getHtmlId(), $childFieldTwo->getName())
        ->addFieldDependence(
            $childFieldTwo->getName(),
            $parentField->getName(),
            '2'
            );
            
            
        $this->setChild('form_after', $dependence1);    
        $this->setChild('form_after', $dependence2);            
        

        $postData = $this->_session->getData('stackexchange_custom_earningpointrule_data', true);
        if ($postData) {
            $post->addData($postData);
        } else {
            if (!$post->getId()) {
                $post->addData($post->getDefaultValues());
            }
        }
                
        $form->addValues($post->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare label for tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Target');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare title for tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->getTabLabel();
    }

    /**
     * Can show tab in tabs
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Tab is hidden
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getTargetTypeOptions() {
        
         return $applyOptions = [
                ['label' => __('Level'),   'value' =>  1],
                ['label' => __('Segment'), 'value' =>  2]
            ];
    }
    
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getTagetTypeMultiselectLevels() {
    
    return [
            ['value' => 1, 'label' => 'Level 1'],
            ['value' => 2, 'label' => 'Level 2'],
            ['value' => 3, 'label' => 'Level 3']
        
           ]; 
           
    }
    
    
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getTagetTypeMultiselectSegments() {
        
    
    
    return [
            ['value' => 1, 'label' => 'segment 1'],
            ['value' => 2, 'label' => 'segment 2'],
            ['value' => 3, 'label' => 'segment 3']
        
           ];
    }
     
    
       
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Please suggest me thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript to do that i have done this in my ui_component form block form musve  same way to do this

```
$parentField = $fieldset->addField('target_type', 
        'select', [
             'name' => 'target_type',
             'component' => 'Vendor_ModuleName/js/form/element/options',
            'label' => __('Target Type'),
            'values' => $this->getTargetTypeOptions(),

        ]);         



        $childFieldOne= $fieldset->addField(
            'target_multiselect_levels',
            'multiselect',
            [
                'name'     => 'target_multiselect_levels',                
                'title' => __('Target Multiselect Levels'),
                'label' => __('Levels'),
                'visible' => false
                'required'=>true,               
                'values' => $this->getTagetTypeMultiselectLevels(),

            ]
        );

        $childFieldTwo=$fieldset->addField(
            'target_multiselect_segments',
            'multiselect',
            [
                'name'     => 'target_multiselect_segments',                
                'title' => __('Target Multiselect Segments'),
                'label' => __('Segments'),
                'visible' => false
                'required'=>true,
                'values' => $this->getTagetTypeMultiselectSegments(),

            ]
        );
```

now go and create

> Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\web\js\options.js

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select, modal) {
    'use strict';
    return select.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        var value=this._super().initialValue; 
        console.log('Selected Value: ' + value);
        var field1 = uiRegistry.get('index = target_multiselect_levels');
        var field2 = uiRegistry.get('index = target_multiselect_segments');
        if (value=='level' ) {
            field1.show();
            field2.hide();
        } else {
            field1.hide();
            field2.show();
        }



        return this._super();
    },
    onUpdate: function (value) { 
        console.log('Selected Value: ' + value);

        var field1 = uiRegistry.get('index = target_multiselect_levels');
        var field2 = uiRegistry.get('index = target_multiselect_segments');
        if (value=='level' ) {
            field1.show();
            field2.hide();
        } else {
            field1.hide();




        return this._super();
    },
});
});
```